# CentOS reinstall after crash (regularly)

Tags: centos

I have an old laptop which runs CentOS 7 and runs a MQTT server, MySQL and few java apps. The laptop sometimes crashes (due to its old age) and forces me to format and reinstall CentOS again. I have to again install all the packages which generally takes a lot of time. I am looking if I can simply create a "copy" of the whole OS with all the packages and restore it whenever required.

Copy can be a custom image or a custom script. I have googled clonezilla, chef and similar tools but I feel that is an overkill for just a single laptop. Custom script solves the packages part but I have to install the OS manually. Any thoughts?

Also I just need the installation. I can habdle db data recovery and application configuration recovery.

Comment: You have to "format and reinstall" after a "crash"? That doesn't make any sense. It also doesn't make any sense that you would be using such an unreliable old laptop for any important business purpose.

Comment: Voting to migrate because in the serverfault scope of a business environment the solution to a crashing laptop is to get the hardware repaired or replaced. - Having said that: Scripting a CentOS install is called a kickstart. It has been ages since I did a manual CentOS install but if i recall correctly after a manual installation the installer creates an kickstart file in /root/ (anaconda.ks?) for you. You can use that file the next time you install to automatically  repeat all the manual choices you made if you don't want to use an imaging solution

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/chap-kickstart-installations

Comment: @Michael Hampton : The crash in my case was due to hardware issues. I did not intend crashes due to software issues. Also this server is only used for showcasing my POC apps. Not much of business impact.

Comment: @HBruijn: Thank you for the reference. I'll go through it.

Answer (score 0):

Do your format and load, then do a dump (that is, a full backup) of all the file systems. To reinstall, format and do a minimal load, then do a restore of all the file systems.

Comment: can you be more specific? Yes the backup and restore is the thing i am looking for but is there any utility that can achieve this. If your referring to the manual backup, i was trying to avoid that.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the dump/restore pair in the dump rpm.